# Not able to find the "SQL Server Project" template in Visual Studio 2010 Professional to work with CLR SQL Server Trigger

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqlclr

I am newbie in working with `CLR SQL Server Trigger`. I am following MSDN [How to Create a SQL Server Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84b1se47(v=vs.90).aspx) link. Point 4 on this page says that I have to select `SQL Server Project` template as my new project.

But in my `Visual Studio 2010 Professional` I am not able to find this option. I have searched and find this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0ccd8061-83b0-40c6-9aa7-b6275abb53b8/missing-database-project-templates-in-vs2010-professional?forum=vssetup). On this link it is written that *"Most of database project functions are available only in Premium Edition and Ultimate Edition"* but nothing is written particularly about `SQL Servery Project` template.

So my question is that:
 Do I really need `Visual Studio Premium or Ultimate` to create `SQL Server Project` template to work with `CLR SQL Server Trigger`?
Or this functionality can also be achieved using `Visual Studio 2010 professional`? If yes then please let me know what kind of project template I need to choose?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

[Install the SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500335(v=vs.103).aspx) (SSDT) found in installing update 1 ([SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691)) of VS2010. Though at the writing of this reply, they are no longer updating that version past that update.

It would be best if you upgrade to the latest version of Visual Studio before beginning any database work since many things have changed.